# Can't set font family in google appscript for gmail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to set font family for text in google appscript for a Gmail add-on but it seems there is no direct way to do that.

I tried this

```
function showCardWithFontFamily() {
  // Create a card
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();

  // Create a card section
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();

  // Create a text paragraph and set its content and font family
  var textParagraph = CardService.newTextParagraph()
    .setText("Hello, this is a text with custom font family.")
    .setFontFamily("Arial");

  // Add the text paragraph to the card section
  section.addWidget(textParagraph);

  // Add the card section to the card
  card.addSection(section);

  // Build the card and return it
  var cardAsWidget = card.build();
  
  // Show the card in the Gmail interface
  return cardAsWidget;
}
```

I got the following error

> TypeError: CardService.newTextParagraph(...).setText(...).setFontFamily is not a function

Comment: There is no setFontFamily() method.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextParagraph` returned by `CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(...)` only supports basic HTML formatting and is the reason why you're getting an error when chaining it with `.setFontFamily()`. Currently, setting a font family is not included in the list of supported HTML tags.

### Reference:

- [Widget text formatting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text-formatting)

### Additional resources:

- [Introducing an easier way to design your G Suite Add-on](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/introducing-easier-way-to-design-your-gsuite-add-on.html)